# Asp.net mvc 3 handling unexpected query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, get

I am just wondering about the situation where the user may request through unexpected query. Suppose i have the controller action

```
  public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            Description description = db.Descriptions.Find(id);
            return View(description);
        }
```

The ideal query in the browser will be `/admin/Details?id=1`.
What if the user entered the `id=-1` or `id=a` or any other unexpected inputs. How to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure numeric values, you could add  `id = @"\d+"` route constraint, and your action will be hit only if requested `id` is numeric, otherwise it will return http not found;

And in all other cases you should always check user input, something like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Description description = db.Descriptions.Find(id); 

    if(description == null)
    {
          return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);
    }

    return View(description);
}
```

And user will be notified that he requested resource with invalid identifier

Comment: It worked but i have a problem. The return type is `ActionResult` however `HttpStatusCodeResult(404)` is a `CodeResult` type.

Comment: HttpStatusCodeResult inherits from ActionResult, so code will execute without problems. Unfortunately I do not understand what "CodeResult type" means

Comment: Adding verification at route would prevent even reaching that controller action if the ID is wrong. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want but I would rather test the ID once in the action to display proper error instead of "Page not found" type error. So perhaps before passing the ID to your db.Descriptions.Find() method, you could test it for being larger then 0.

Comment: Now that I think about it, there should already be an error if the ID is not a int as the binder will fail to parse it into a int (as it's a non-nullable type)... Hmmm. I'd have to test the exact behavior, but yea, just keep in mind that route restriction = not even reaching the action.